# Raspberry Pi Commands

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

How does one do a print screen in Raspian? I used the scrot command to no avail. Also, how do I enlarge the capture to focus it better? Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use VNC to view the interface of your Raspberry Pi to your desktop/laptop and then take a print screen from there. Here is the documentation of VNC from the official site:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/